# typedef vs extend classes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a base class

```
abstract class Repository<T> {
  Future<List<T>> getAll();
  Future<T> getByID(int id);
}
```

Then I would extend it just to specify type. But Dart has interesting syntax `typedef ... = ...`. What is better?

Classic way

```
abstract class UserRepository extends Repository<User>{}
```

Another way

```
typedef UserRepository = Repository<User>;
```

Last is more aesthetic

What pros and cons for every way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use inheritance, because typedef required for creating aliases.

```
abstract class Repository<T> {
  Future<List<T>> getAll();

  Future<T> getByID(int id);
}

// with alias
typedef UserRepository = Repository<User>;

class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepository {
    ...
}

// without alias
class UserRepositoryImpl extends Repository<User> {
    ...
}
```